# If statement depending on the random image shown

Tags: android, random

I have a imageview that randomly generate 1 out of 2 possibles images clicking on one button.

I want that when one image is showed (R.drawable.aa) and I press other button, a toast is shown.

My problem is that once a random image is shown and click on the other button, nothing happens.

```
 package com.example.isaiasalarcon.menu;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.isaiasalarcon.menu.R.drawable.aa;

public class buho extends Activity   {

    // UI components
    private Button drawButton;
    private Button boton2;
    private ImageView cardImage;

    // Random object
    private final static Random random = new Random();



    // The card deck
    private final static int[] cardDeck = new int[] {
            R.drawable.aa,
            R.drawable.a2,
             };
    private Integer q;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buho);

        drawButton  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.drawButton);
        boton2  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        cardImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cardImage);



        drawButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Integer q = cardDeck[random.nextInt(cardDeck.length)];
                cardImage.setImageResource(q);

  }
        });

        boton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (q.equals(R.drawable.aa)) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(buho.this, "si", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                } else {
                   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(buho.this, "no", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();

                }


            }
        });
   }

}
```

Comment: Is this an Android app? Looks like Java and there's an Activity base class.

Comment: Given that he also used the term "Toast" I would say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two things:

1) `Integer q` I don't see a reason why this needs to be an Integer. You should be able to `int`

2) your `q` inside the onClick is creating a NEW variable called `q`. You need to update your code to the following: (note how it doesn't have the Type declaration before it, so it means to use the previously declared variable)

```
  drawButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            q = cardDeck[random.nextInt(cardDeck.length)];
            cardImage.setImageResource(q);

        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks! Now is working perfectly. I have set q as a final int at the beggining.